# Tactical map not showing in Company of Heroes 2

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

I'm trying to use the tactical map in CoH2 and it's simply not showing.

I have a keyboard without a numpad, so I initially thought that was the problem. I remapped the tilde (`) key to numpad 0, but that didn't help. It worked in notepad because typing ` would result in a 0 (assuming numlock is on) or it would toggle insert mode (if numpad was off).

I then tried plugging in another keyboard - one that *does* have a numpad. And yet still the tactical map will not come up.

I also tried switching between the different key modes (classic versus non-classic) and the problem persists.

Finally, I tried classic missions because until then I had been trying Ardennes and thought maybe the tactical map wasn't available there for some reason. It still didn't work.

What the heck is going on? How do I get the tactical map to come up?

Comment: My first thought is to maybe try doing an integrity check (if you are using Steam) to see if any files are corrupt/missing, I've had a similar issue before where the assets for the minimap weren't loading.

Comment: @ranger10700 Thanks for the suggestion. I do use Steam. I just tried running an integrity check and it completed without reporting any issue. All the same, I ran the game again and tried to bring up tactical map and I still can't bring it up.

Comment: Are other hotkeys working normally? Can you open the tactical map with your mouse? Can you please try to map the button to something else than a special character?

Comment: I have already tried mapping to tilde, F1 and F2. None has worked. But even a standard keyboard doesn't work, so I don't believe this has anything to do with mapping. If a standard numpad 0 doesn't work, why would a mapped one?

Comment: Good point. Can you please try a different computer?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen just tried installing on my laptop. Tactical map came up without a fuss :/

Comment: @AulisRonkainen well, turns out the tactical map also doesn't work on my laptop _during campaigns_. It only works in skirmish. Wtf? Is this expected?

Comment: Confirmed. I tried tactical map in skirmish using my original machine with original keyboard + keymap. It works fine! So it seems tactical map only works for skirmish? I am shook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I figured out tactical map *does* work in skirmish, it was easy to Google and confirm this inexplicable oversight. For example, from [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/231430/discussions/0/558754259798952708/):

> Nevermind it appears it is only available in online gameplay.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out. Great work!